# Variable changes on all spawned enemies instead of changing only on self

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Ok so I am trying to make this work for a week now and I ran out of solutions.

I am spawning an enemy on a specified spawn point. Then I am randomizing his index. (The index specifies the type of the enemy)

But every time I add one more enemy to the scene they both have the same index for some reason. After killing one of them the index of the other comes back to normal.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem, please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB3r7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Iko4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you had set different Materials in your `Current Material`, correctly.

problem should be this:

To use `Set Material` instead of `Create Dynamic Material Instance`

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Rendering/Material/SetMaterial/index.html

Comment: That I already know but it does not solve my problem and Create Dynamic Material Instance from what I read is more performance-friendly.

Comment: What I need to get solved is that the array index is changing on all the enemyes spawned in the scene, not on one only.

Comment: Maybe your `Current Array Index` or `Mesh`  is common, Where is it located?
Try to give us whole screen, may there are some misunderstanding.

Comment: I think you ware right they are common. But how do I make the otherwise?

Comment: your first picture, where is it?   is that in your enemy class?

Comment: Yes all the three pictures are the enemy class

Comment: Oh, the system wasn't tell me until you add a comment here, I'll glad to have a discord call, how may I contact you?
Discord:KwangSinG#0732

Comment: I've sent you a friend request

Answer (score 0):

The array index is a variable in the enemy actor class, the mesh material is controlled by the array index so it does not matter, I think.

Maybe we can do a discord call or something and you can take a look because I wasted a lot of time trying to figure this problem out but I had no luck.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32hGK.png)

Comment: @KwangSing this is what i have